# Can't assign ip address to veth directly after creating veth pair

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, network-interface, virtual-network

If I run the following, then the ip address doesn't actually get added:

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1; ip address add 10.0.1.2/24 dev veth1
```

However if I sleep in between the commands, then it does get added:

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1; sleep 0.1; ip address add 10.0.1.2/24 dev veth1
```

I've repeated multiple times and the results are consistent.

Is there a nicer way of doing this rather than just sleeping in between?

UPDATE:

Using ip montitor, it seems that a load of stuff is being done when the veth pair is created (no idea what), and that when both commands are run on the same line (without sleep), the ip address creation stops a lot of this stuff being done and the ip addresses get automatically deleted.

Does anyone understand what all this stuff is which happens when the veth pair is created?

output of ip monitor for veth creation:

```
ipv4 dev veth1 forwarding on rp_filter strict mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
ipv6 dev veth1 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
372: veth1@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether da:a6:13:1a:29:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ipv4 dev veth0 forwarding on rp_filter strict mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
ipv6 dev veth0 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
373: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 4a:9e:6c:13:13:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
372: veth1@veth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default 
    link/ether da:a6:13:1a:29:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
373: veth0@veth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default 
    link/ether 4a:9e:6c:13:13:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
373: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 4a:9e:6c:13:13:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
372: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether da:a6:13:1a:29:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
372: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether da:a6:13:1a:29:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
373: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 4a:9e:6c:13:13:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
372: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether da:a6:13:1a:29:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
373: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 4a:9e:6c:13:13:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

ip monitor output for adding ip address:

```
372: veth1    inet 10.0.1.2/24 scope global veth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
local 10.0.1.2 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.1.2
10.0.1.0/24 dev veth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
broadcast 10.0.1.0 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
broadcast 10.0.1.255 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2
```

ip monitor output when running both on same line (without sleep). The *'s indicate the line which is the start of the ip address creation:

```
ipv4 dev veth1 forwarding on rp_filter strict mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
ipv6 dev veth1 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
374: veth1@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 72:94:ec:5a:d7:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ipv4 dev veth0 forwarding on rp_filter strict mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
ipv6 dev veth0 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
375: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether b6:7f:f2:e5:69:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
****************************************************************
374: veth1    inet 10.0.1.2/24 scope global veth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
****************************************************************
local 10.0.1.2 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.1.2 
375: veth0@veth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default 
    link/ether b6:7f:f2:e5:69:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
374: veth1@veth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default 
    link/ether 72:94:ec:5a:d7:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10.0.1.0/24 dev veth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
broadcast 10.0.1.0 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
broadcast 10.0.1.255 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
374: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:94:ec:5a:d7:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
375: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether b6:7f:f2:e5:69:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 10.0.1.0/24 dev veth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
Deleted 374: veth1    inet 10.0.1.2/24 scope global veth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
Deleted broadcast 10.0.1.255 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
Deleted broadcast 10.0.1.0 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 
Deleted local 10.0.1.2 dev veth1 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.1.2 
375: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether b6:7f:f2:e5:69:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
374: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:94:ec:5a:d7:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
375: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether b6:7f:f2:e5:69:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev veth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
374: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:94:ec:5a:d7:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev veth1 table local metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
374: veth1    inet6 fe80::1ab9:60e6:dfe2:5904/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
local fe80::1ab9:60e6:dfe2:5904 dev veth1 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
374: veth1    inet6 fe80::1ab9:60e6:dfe2:5904/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
Deleted fe80::/64 dev veth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth1 proto kernel metric 102 pref medium
375: veth0    inet6 fe80::aa07:cb3f:757e:f3f4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
local fe80::aa07:cb3f:757e:f3f4 dev veth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
375: veth0    inet6 fe80::aa07:cb3f:757e:f3f4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
Deleted fe80::/64 dev veth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth0 proto kernel metric 101 pref medium
```

Comment: Can you retry the first command, but while running `ip monitor` in another terminal? Does it show the address being added and quickly removed, or does it show nothing at all?

Comment: It's a race condition: The kernel must finish adding the card before it can configure it, even if the `ip` command returns. If for some reason adding is slow, you must wait until it appears. You can loop on `ip link show | grep veth1` etc., but if `sleep` already works...

Comment: @grawity Thanks for that, I've updated the question with the ip monitor output